# How to make a dropdown list in bootstrap?

Tags: html, dropdown

I am trying to make a bootstrap navbar with dropdown, but I can't figure out why my dropdown doesn't work.

```html
<nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img class= "logo" src="LogoRegionalPost.png" width="140" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt=""></a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="index.html">Acasa<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Politica</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Administratie</a>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Economie</a>
            <a class="nav-item dropdown nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Dropdown
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action 1</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action 2</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action 3</a>
            </div></div>
    
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Hello, please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This will increase your chance to get an appropriate answer. Furthermore it also helps you solving the question yourself. Currently your question has no javascript or css or anything. No one can reproduce your problem with your question in this state.

Answer (score 0):

the bootstrap dropdown needs the corresponding javascript-file.

> Dropdowns are built on a third party library, Popper.js, which provides dynamic positioning and viewport detection. Be sure to include popper.min.js before Bootstrap’s JavaScript or use bootstrap.bundle.min.js / bootstrap.bundle.js which contains Popper.js. Popper.js isn’t used to position dropdowns in navbars though as dynamic positioning isn’t required. [Source](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/)

maybe you forgot to add the bootstrap.js ?

Answer (score 0):

Please don't forget to add the bootstrap js dependencies :

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img class="logo" src="LogoRegionalPost.png" width="140" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt=""></a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
    <div class="navbar-nav">
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="index.html">Acasa<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Politica</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Administratie</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Economie</a>
      <a class="nav-item dropdown nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Dropdown
      </a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action 1</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action 2</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</nav>

<!-- ADD BOOTSTRAP JS FILES -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

You will find this files [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/introduction/#js).